# JavaScript Date object not working with string passed to it

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to create a date object by using a variable obtained from a database. The string is already in the correct format, already comma delimited "yyyy,mm,dd,hh,mm,ss". However trying to create a Date object returns an Invalid Date error.

```
var foo ='2012,03,09,12,00,00,00';
document.write(foo); //<-- obviously writes the string 2012,03,09,12,00,00,00 to the browser
var then=(new Date(foo));
document.write(then); //<-- returns Invalid Date
```

I have a solution which is the following:

```
var x = foo.split(/[,]/);
var then = new Date(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]);
```

Wondering why this is needed when essentially it's recreating the same string that was passed to it.

Comment: A Date isn't a string. new Date(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]) isn't using a string but 6 strings, the ones needed for the creation of the Date object.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the string you are trying to convert into a Date object is not valid. The Date object doesn't just accept any format as a string. if it is not recognised it wont work.

See Date doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Here is information about format supported

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14

Answer (score 1):

`"yyyy,mm,dd,hh,mm,ss"` is *not* a "correct format" for a date string.

The JavaScript `Date` object can only parse specific formats.  Check the MDN docs for `Date` for valid `dateString`s.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Anyway. your 2nd example works because you're *not* recreating the string, you are are passing 6 different parameters compared to one long one.

You can't pass a comma-separated string to a function and expect it to break it into parameters, it doesn't work that way.

Comment: You can set a Date by new Date(yyyy,mm,dd,hh,mm,ss) just wondering why using a variable wouldn't act the same way.

Comment: because your variable is a single string. You are passing in one argument, not 6.

Comment: @rmuser: Because when you do `new Date(yyyy,mm,dd,hh,mm,ss)`, you're passing 6 individual parameters.  `new Date(foo)` is just one parameter.  It's not going to break it up into different parameters for you, JavaScript doesn't work that way.

Comment: point taken. thx to all who replied. i posted this on another forum and all i received back was that it should work. sorry to beat a dead horse. i guess i know where to come first in the future.